# Как обновить WebView с помощью Swipe Refresh?

Tags: android-studio, webview, swipe

Я не программист, это моя первая программа, поэтому могли бы вы подсказать поподробнее как мне обновить WebView с помощью Swipe Refresh.
Мне нужно чтобы страничка WebView обновлялась свайпом, т.к.я ни знаю как это сделать, но у меня получилось собрать кое какую программу, но она не обновляет странички. Когда я на сайте меняю содержимое, то в приложении содержимое остается прежним

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.mywebsite.myapplic;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.net.URI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//initializing WebView
private WebView mwebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //WebView
    mwebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mwebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //improve webView performance
    mwebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    mwebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    mwebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mwebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);


    mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/");
    //force links open in webview only
    mwebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_0) {
        // Handle the camera action
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_1) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/цикл-forцикл-со-счетчиком/");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_2) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/цикл-while/");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_3) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/цикл-с-постусловием-repeat/");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_4) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/одномерные-массивы/");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_5) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/функции/");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_6) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/процедуры/");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_7) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/тесты/");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_8) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/кимы/");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_9) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://abramovn.16mb.com/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8/");
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private class MyWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://abramovn.16mb.com/")) {
            //open url contents in webview
            return false;
        } else {
            //here open external links in external browser or app
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }
    //ProgressDialogue
    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
        pd.setMessage("Website is Loading..");
        pd.show();
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        pd.dismiss();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
//goto previous page when pressing back button

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mwebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mwebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы страничка WebView обновлялась свайпом, т.к. я не программист я ни знаю как это сделать, но у меня получилось собрать кое какую программу, но она не обновляет странички. Когда я на сайте меняю содержимое, то в приложении содержимое остается прежним.